# removing common words from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove common words from a text. for example the sentence

"It is not a commonplace river, but on the contrary is in all ways remarkable."

I want to turn it into just unique words. This means removing "it", "but", "a" etc. I have a text file that has all the common words and another text file that contains a paragraph. How can I delete the common words in the paragraph text file?

For example:

```
['It', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'commonplace', 'river', 'but', 'on', 'the', 'contrary', 'is', 'in', 'all', 'ways', 'remarkable']
```

How do I remove the common words from the file efficiently. I have a text file called common.txt that has all the common words listed. How do I use that list to remove identical words in the sentence above. End output I want:

```
['commonplace', 'river', 'contrary', 'remarkable']
```

Does that make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: What you want to do is to remove the [stopwords](https://pythonspot.com/nltk-stop-words/) Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) though.

Comment: where is your exact problem? reading two files? creating sets or list from your words? removing one sets words from the other sets words? do you need the words of the paragraph in order (=> use a list) or not (=> use sets and set-operations)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: are you ok with NLTK stopwords approach ?

Comment: @gilbo184 We care about _specific questions and problems_ yours looks like a `gimme code` - type of question. Please be more specific so this is answerable and provides reference for future ppl searching and finding this question.

Answer (score 2):

you would want to use "set" objects in python.

If order and number of occurrence are not important:

```
str_list = ['It', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'commonplace', 'river', 'but', 'on', 'the', 'contrary', 'is', 'in', 'all', 'ways', 'remarkable']

common_words = ['It', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'but', 'on', 'the', 'in', 'all', 'ways','other_words']

set(str_list) - set(common_words)

>>> {'contrary', 'commonplace', 'river', 'remarkable'}
```

If both are important:

```
#Using "set" is so much faster
common_set = set(common_words)

[s for s in str_list if not s in common_set]

>>> ['commonplace', 'river', 'contrary', 'remarkable']
```

Comment: this looses the order of the words in the original text - if that is no longer needed (which the OP did not confirm as asked by the comment) it might be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that you can use:

```
l = text.replace(",","").replace(".","").split(" ")
occurs = {}
for word in l:
    occurs[word] = l.count(word)

resultx = ''
for word in occurs.keys()
    if occurs[word] < 3:
        resultx += word + " "

resultx = resultx[:-1]
```

> you can change 3 with what you think suited or based it on the average using :

`occurs.values()/len(occurs)`

**Additional**

if you want it to be Case insensitive change the 1st line with :

`l = text.replace(",","").replace(".","").lower().split(" ")`

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try

Comment: @gilbo184 I'll welcome any follow-up, and I'd appreciate you aceept my answer if u find it helpful ;)

Comment: You explained it very well, ill get coding tonight and get back to you.

Comment: You are creating a count of words - use module collections and class `Counter` for it - its much more efficient then what you do - for a text of 1000 words you analyze the text 1000 times and count one words occurence on each analyze. Counter uses one pass of the text to get all counts. Your answer also does not answer the OP - he has a list of words to be removed already in a file ... that he wants to remove from text in another file. you do not adress this at all.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I know, but that can only be a problem for python if working in BigData not a thousand words or even 100k, no need to complicate things if it wasn't a necessity

Answer (score 0):

Most simple method would be just to `read()` your `common.txt` and then use *list comprehension* and only take the words that are `not in` the file we read

```
with open('common.txt') as f:
    content = f.read()

s = ['It', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'commonplace', 'river', 'but', 'on', 'the', 'contrary', 'is', 'in', 'all', 'ways', 'remarkable']

res = [i for i in s if i not in content]
print(res)
# ['commonplace', 'river', 'contrary', 'remarkable']
```

`filter` also works here

```
res = list(filter(lambda x: x not in content, s))
```